# Virtual Box - Bridged network adapter

Tags: virtualbox, dedicated-server

i recently bought a dedicated server off hetzner. i am currently using virtual box (oracle) for running a server but choosing bridged network returns me no DCHP inet IP to go on and run the server publicly

is there anything i can do to fix this ?

Comment: What's your host OS? A bridged network works for a home connection because you're behind a lan - which has a range of IPs. Generally a dedicated server comes with one IP with additional ones  needing to be configured separately.  The exact settings you need to make may vary

Comment: Your server may have been given one IP address that everything goes to. You probably need to use a NATted network, and port forward to the internal servers, like with a normal router. Alternatively, buy a 2nd IP Address and configure it manually using bridged

Comment: Yeah this was it , needed additional ip - OS windows server had to virtualize didnt run natively